# Google OR tools: Routing problem integrated to scheduling

Tags: python, solver, or-tools, cp-sat

I would like to optimize a problem that integrates the machine scheduling with routing problems. It means, I would like to jointly optimize the machine scheduling (which depends on the cost of tasks executed by each machine) and also the cost of transferring material from one machine to another (which depends on the distance between them).

I am using CP-SAT. I already stated the problem for scheduling, so I would like integrate the optimization of routing distance using CP-SAT as well.

I found examples of routing problems specific for the routing solver. But I still not found for CP-SAT.

My questions are:

1) Is it appropriate to optimize routing problems with CP-SAT?
2) Which variable in CP-SAT could replace *IndexToNode()*? I am wondering that the InvervalVar would be appropriated but I am not sure.
3) Is there an example of routing problem using CP-SAT?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Found a TSP example: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/tsp_sat.py

Comment: @Stradivari, thanks. I am looking for an example in which the traveler not necessary visit all nodes, and there is a decision variable related to that. Would you know an similar example?